# Why does God curse and how does it align with justice?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit, curse

> וְעַתָּה אָרוּר אָתָּה מִן־הָאֲדָמָה אֲשֶׁר פָּצְתָה אֶת־פִּיהָ לָקַחַת אֶת־דְּמֵי אָחִיךָ מִיָּדֶךָ׃ - >Therefore, you shall be more cursed than the ground, which opened its mouth to receive your brother’s blood from your hand. [Genesis.4.11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.4.11?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)

God's curses are regular in the Torah, but I find it difficult to comprehend God's cursing. As God is just, I would expect a clear punishment for every sin, not some kind of a prolonged amorphous misfortune.

What does God's curse mean, why does he curse and how does it align with justice?

Comment: Why do you assume the curse is amorphous? The specifics of the curse are laid out in the next verses.